# property initialization in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, class, properties

I have created a class in JavaScript like this:

```
var Test = function(){
    this.element = null;
    this.init = function() {
        if(Test.html == "") {
            Test.loadHtml(this);
            return;
        }
        this.initElements();
        this.someMethodInternalCall();
    };
    this.initElements = function() {
        // append the loaded html to body
        // etc...
        this.element = $("some-element-contained-in-loaded-html-apended-to-body");
    }
    this.someMethodInternalCall = function() {
        this.element.css({some:style}); // works in this place
    }
    this.someMethodExternalCall = function() {
        this.element.css({some:style}); // dosn't work in this place
        // I mean here this.element is null. WHY?
    }
};
Test.html = "";
Test.loadHtml = function() {
    // load html content by an ajax request (jQuery $.ajax method)
    // and put it in Test.html
    // then recall the Test.init ethod
    return function(caller) {
        Test.html = // load html by ajax... etc...
        caller.init();
    };
}();

function someUsage(){
    var t = new Test();
    t.init();
    t.element.css({some:style}); // error: t.element is null WHY?
    t.someMethodExternalCall(); // error: this.element is null WHY?
}
```

As you can see, I explain in code above. Why when we set properties after their initialization, it just takes effects in internall calls? How can I create a property that I can change it's value?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that I have to explain my code. The probelem is all about `element` property, not `Test.html` nor `Test.loadHtml` method or calling it. `Test.loadHtml` get fired currectly (you can test it) and `Test.html` gets the loaded html and the loaded html get appended to `body` and so on. This is a JavaScript pattern (I forgot what is its name) and works currectly. The only thing that is wrong is about property initialization -`element`.

Comment: what's this is your code? `Test.html = "";` whenever the script will be executed then Test.html will equal to NULL...

Comment: Probelm is not with `Test.html`. It is about `element`.

Comment: `caller` is not `undefined`. Please test code. It works until second call to `element`

Comment: @apsillers +1 yes I got understand this after this problem. But question is how to handle that? I have tried `var self = this;` and working by `self` instead of `this`, but the problem exists

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post a working example of your code on a site like http://jsfiddle.net. Your current code is not functional (e.g., there's some pseudocode and you use `Text.loadHtml` instead of `Test.loadHtml`), so it makes it difficult to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: does `$` actually return a non-null value? jQuery should, but we don't know if it _is_ jQuery.

Comment: I actually implemented a functioning version of your code, and it seems to work perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/8U2Fp/

Comment: Javascript does not have "classes".

Comment: ` The only thing that is wrong is about property initialization -element.` Then please _abstract away_ all the things that do work and are not relevant to the problem. They should not at all be part of this question.

Comment: Update: this question is not a Case of the Mistaken `this` (so the flagged duplicate is incorrect), but it probably *is* a Case of Misunderstood Asynchronous Operation, as @StuartWakefield has wisely guessed, despite the Ajax code not being omitted from the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is asynchronicity. When you are going off to load the HTML via AJAX the rest of the function continues...

```
function someUsage(){
  var t = new Test();
  t.init();
  // The following carries on whilst the request is loading it does not wait
  t.element.css({some:style}); // This is why I am null
  t.someMethodExternalCall(); // This is why I am also null
}
```

To get around this you could use a callback...

```
function someUsage(){
  var t = new Test();
  t.init(function() {
    // I do not continue until the loadHtml request has completed
    t.element.css({some:style}); // I am not null anymore
    t.someMethodExternalCall(); // I am not null anymore
  });
}
```

You would need to modify your init function and your loadHtml function to call the callback rather than the init method of the caller object, the init function...

```
this.init = function(callback) {

  // Using blank Test.html to determine whether the html has been loaded
  if(Test.html == "") {
    var me = this;

    // Call loadHtml with a callback function
    Text.loadHtml(function() {

      // I want to keep the this reference to the object and callback argument
      me.init(callback);
    });

  // It is loaded so continue set up and then trigger the callback
  } else {
    this.initElements();
    this.someMethodInternalCall();
    callback();
  }
};
```

There would still cause a problem if you created a number of these Test classes as each would try to get the HTML whilst the others were loading.

To get around this you just need to have a flag that is set by the first call. Any subsequent calls are ignored but the callbacks are recorded to be called when the HTML finishes loading...

```
Test.loadHtml = function(callback) {

  // If already loading roll up callbacks
  if(Test.loading) {

    // Callback becomes a function that calls the original callback function 
    // and then the new one
    Test.callback = (function(original) {
      return function() {
        original();
        callback();
      }
    }) (Test.callback);

  // First time it has been called set the flag to prevent multiple loads 
  // and add the callback
  } else {
    Test.loading = true;
    Test.callback = callback;

    // Added to illustrate the AJAX callback functionality
    ajax("html", function(response) {
      Test.html = response;
      Test.callback();
    });
  }
}();
```

The preferred approach is to enforce object validity at instantiation time, this prevents these race conditions. You throw an error if the class cannot be constructed validly, this moves the complexity surrounding the order of your operations from the class. As you can see below it is not as pretty and you have to call the load step yourself (or have something else trigger it).

```
new Test(); // Errors not loaded!
// We must perform the load step to use the class
Test.load(function() {
  new Test(); // Works!
});
```

The more elegant solution, especially for large applications, involves managing access to the class. You cannot access the class without first performing the loading step, this enforces that loading will always complete before the class is instantiated.

```
// views is some object managing the loading of view classes when asked for
// one or more views it will load the required HTML and return the class(es)
// so we can create instances...
views.load("Test", function(Test) {
  var t = new Test();
  t.element.css({some: style});
  t.someMethodExternalCall();
});
```

Comment: No probs, glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing `caller.init();` in the callback of the ajax function in `loadHtml`?

If not, your init function will be added to the execution stack before your html is loaded (and that's why `this.element` is null)

```
Test.loadHtml = function() {
    // load html content by an ajax request (jQuery $.ajax method)
    // and put it in Test.html
    // then recall the Test.init ethod
    return function(caller) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'somethinghere',
        success: function(data) {
            Test.html = data;
            caller.init();
        }
      });
    };
```